# Isometric tilemap in unity - sorting issues

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine, layer, isometric

ok I've been searching everywhere and cannot understand this, hopefully someone here can help!
I am building a game in unity with an isometric tilemap, and apparently I can't grasp the whole sorting issue, cause nothing I do works as I wish...
to start this is the scene: [basic scene with player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgv5B.jpg)

the whole basic scene is in one tilemap (I also have a map for collision, floor and upper level but those aren't relevant to the problem in hand - at least I don't think so...), which is set to individual and the graphic settings are 0,1,1 (I also tried changing those with no success)

when the player stands close to a tile it sorts incorrectly [incorrect sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX8Qt.jpg), obviously this is solved if I change to chunk mode but then everything else gets messed up  [chunk mode, tables sort wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDSdx.jpg) and also this happens for some reason - the player sorts behind some of the tiles [player sorts behind tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoLVK.jpg)

any help would be appreciated
omer

Comment: I don’t know for certain that they’re relevant to your issue but just mentioning that a number of tutorials and people receiving help with similar issues come up with a Google search for ‘unity isometric tile sort’. Worth checking if you don’t find the answer here.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I think I already gone through all possible videos, even those in your suggested search, sadly they didn't help...

Comment: Sorry to hear that :/. If it’s not related to the sprite sorting order settings, maybe check that the pivot position on the sprites isn’t somehow messed up?